# How to get value on change if using materialize css?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

How to get the value from on change if I'm using Materialize CSS?
Without Materialize CSS, I'm using dropdown attribute, and everytime dropdown change it will get the value.

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
          <select id="name">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Name</option>
            <option value="1">John</option>
            <option value="2">Doe</option>
            <option value="3">Kim</option>
          </select>
          <label>Name Selection</label>
</div>
```

Now in Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();

  });


function generateTable(dataArray){
var name = document.getElementById("name");

     name.onchange = function(){
        
        console.log(this.value);
      }
}
```

Seem like this.value didn't return any value from dropdown. Any suggestion?

Comment: how do you cann **function generateTable(dataArray){** and the parameter....??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

As for me it works, I think you need to call generateTable().

Comment: Hi, Sorry I'm still new in Javascript but from what I understand from you picture, your console.log return as number which same case as mine. But I want it to return the name because I want to use it with IndexOf.

Comment: Hi, sorry my bad. It actually work. I forgot to delete value in <option>

Comment: @AsyrafSyahmi As  I see my answer marked as not useful, why ? )  Cos the cod is working, what did I have to answer?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I still new with Stack Overflow. I didn't remember that I clicked that upvote and downvote button. For me, your answer is useful but everytime I click upvote button this error pop up "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." and it become -1 again. I have no idea why that's happen. Let me know what can I do. I will surely help you.

Comment: I think if you see that nothing to else in this question mark as completed and mark this answer as useful for you.